# Sankey arrows Inverts when plotting with connect

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, sankey-diagram

I am trying to plot a Sankey plot using the matplotlib code below. The code works fine when I try to plot them separately. However, when I combine them, the direction of 'one' of the arrows is opposite when plotted combined.
I tried to troubleshoot, but I am completely oblivious to why this is happening. Can anyone provide their feedback?

```py
a = [1008590.0368940466, -368142.35465001286, -34409.668598874494, -369212.57399895444, -236736.40069105377, -89.03895515092165]
b = [199910.4894048177, 15518.603443203947, 143514.46418879204, 231094.9357130916, 44.28348931634303, -590082.7762392217]

from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10,5], dpi = 300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,)
sankey = Sankey(ax=ax, 
                scale=0.0000003, 
                offset= 0,
                format = '%d',shoulder = 0.02)

sankey.add(flows=a, 
           labels = ['Input', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Remote (Forest)', 'Other'], 
           orientations=[0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1],#arrow directions,
           pathlengths = [0.05,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.1, 0.1],
           trunklength = 0.5,
           edgecolor = '#2b8cbe',
           facecolor = '#2b8cbe')

diagrams = sankey.finish()
for diagram in diagrams:
    for text in diagram.texts:
        text.set_fontsize(10);
plt.axis("off") 
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10,5], dpi = 300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,)
sankey = Sankey(ax=ax, 
                scale=0.0000006, 
                offset= 0,
                format = '%d',shoulder = 0.02)

sankey.add(flows=b, 
           labels = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Remote (Forest)-I', 'Other', 'Forest-Resilience'], 
           orientations=[-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0],#arrow directions,
           pathlengths = [0.2,0.42,0.6,0.1,0.1,0.1],
           trunklength = 0.5, 
           connect = (4,3),
           edgecolor = '#2ca25f',
           facecolor = '#2ca25f')

diagrams = sankey.finish()
for diagram in diagrams:
    for text in diagram.texts:
        text.set_fontsize(10);
plt.axis("off") 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Combined plot code:

```py
from matplotlib.sankey import Sankey
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = [10,5], dpi = 330)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1,)
sankey = Sankey(ax=ax, 
                scale=0.0000006, 
                offset= 0,
                format = '%d',shoulder = 0.02, tolerance=6000)
## Had to add tolerance, otherwise the plots would not combine

sankey.add(flows=a, 
           labels = ['Input', 'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Remote (Forest)', 'Other'], 
           orientations=[0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1],#arrow directions,
           pathlengths = [0.05,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.1, 0.1],
           trunklength = 0.5,
           edgecolor = '#2b8cbe',
           facecolor = '#2b8cbe')

sankey.add(flows=b, 
           #labels = ['Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Remote (Forest)-I', 'Other', 'Forest-Resilience'], 
           orientations=[-1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0],#arrow directions,
           pathlengths = [0.2,0.42,0.6,0.1,0.1,0.1],
           trunklength = 0.5, 
           prior =0, connect = (4,3),
           edgecolor = '#2ca25f',
           facecolor = '#2ca25f')

sankey.add(flows=[b[0],-b[0]], 
           #labels = ['Low'], 
           orientations=[1, 1],#arrow directions,
           pathlengths = [0.1,0.1],
           trunklength = 0.27, 
           prior = 1, connect = (0,1),
           edgecolor = None,
           facecolor = '#99d8c9', hatch = '....', zorder = -2, label = 'False', alpha = 0.2)

diagrams = sankey.finish()
diagrams[0].texts[4].set_position(xy=[1.1, 0.4])
diagrams[1].texts[3].set_position(xy=[1.55, 0.23])
diagrams[2].texts[0].set_position(xy=[1.55,-0.2])

for diagram in diagrams:
    for text in diagram.texts:
        text.set_fontsize(10);
plt.axis("off") 
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Check the *'44' (in green)* arrow's direction.  It is opposite direction in the top and bottom figure)**.

Answer (score 0):

44 is smaller than the tolerance. The magnitude of that flow is 44±6000, so basically you're telling it that you don't know whether that's an input or an output, causing the behavior you're seeing.

You set that tolerance as a workaround for the difference between the connecting flows `Remote (Forest)` (236736) and `Remote (Forest)-I` (231094). I suggest adding a flow for the missing `I`, so that you don't need to rely on tolerance to  fudge the numbers.